# Is this a load-bearing wall seen on this architectural building plan?

Tags: walls, load-bearing, interior, renovation, project-planning

**Hello community!**

I wanted to ask if anyone could assist in figuring out whether this wall is load-bearing based on this architectural building plan?? This wall is currently the back of a reach-in closet, but I wanted to build an interior door connecting the bedroom to the adjoining bathroom. Sorry I'm a newbie to all this, but very excited to figure it out. TIA!

EDIT: Based on the comments, I've added additional pics for clarity

- pretty sure this is a Truss roof: there are comments in the building plans that say truss roof, and this home was built in the last 15 years
- this wall is on the first story/ground level: so no column below. That being said there are 3 columns in the living room area outside this room, none of which directly line up with this wall

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is pretty impossible to tell without a full set of plans including roof framing. Is this a truss roof ? Chances are this is not a bearing wall but cannot be definitive without more info.

Comment: Get an engineer to tell you. Trusting denizens on the net is not good in this case.

Comment: Is there a column below this wall?

Comment: Thank you. Based on the comments, I've added additional pics for clarity

- pretty sure this is a Truss roof: there are comments in the building plans that say truss roof, and this home was built in the last 15 years
- this wall is on the first story/ground level: so no column below. That being said there are columns in the living room, none of which directly line up with this wall